# How to display only some terms of a specific vocabulary in Views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy vocabulary (Drupal 7) called "Categories", with 6 terms: a, b, c, d, e, f

I can't see a way to create a view that will show just terms b, d, e (i.e. any sub-set of the full term list).

This seems like something that should be easy to do. Hopefully it is and I am just missing something, though an hour of searching has turned up nothing...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieve through View,

1. Create a view based on the Taxonomy (Strucutre->view->View settings)
2. Choose Page or Block View.
3. Select the desire fields in the field section
4. Add the taxonomy vocabulary ( categories) and Add term in Filter criteria, and select the Drop down, select the select the hirarchy.

Then it will show the term what you want to filter, select the b,d,e terms over there

And then, b,d and e terms only will be shown in View.

Comment: That was it! I feel silly that I couldn't figure that out, but now I know... Thanks!